# How to Specify Arrowhead Color

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I've been researching this question on how best to specify just an arrowhead's color. I've tried a Graphics primitive but to no avail. I've written this code and would like to color just the arrowheads (say) red. It would also be nice to select specific arrowheads and assign them a specified color. Any assistance would be most welcomed!!

```
  edges = {TX -> R1, R1 -> R3, R5 -> RX, TX -> R2, R2 -> R4, R4 -> R6, 
   R6 -> RX, R1 -> R2, R2 -> R3, R4 -> R5, R5 -> R6, TX -> R7, 
   TX -> R8, R7 -> R9, R9 -> R6, R9 -> RX, R8 -> R6};
g = LayeredGraphPlot[edges, Left, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Lighter[Blue], Arrowheads[0.025], 
      Arrow[#1, 0.3]} &), 
  VertexShapeFunction -> ({Lighter[LightYellow], 
      EdgeForm[Lighter[Blue]], Disk[#, .35], Black, 
      Text[Style[#2, 9.5, Black], #1]} &)]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify any graphics for the head:

```
Arrowheads[{{0.03, 0.8, {Graphics[{Blue, Polygon[{{-1, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/2}, {-1, 1/2}}]}], 0}}}]
```

[image]

You can browse all edge-shape functions, extract their primitives and modify them if you want:

```
GraphComputation`GraphElementData[#, "ArrowSize" -> size][{pt1, pt2, pt3}, edge] & /@ ResourceData["EdgeShapeFunction"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

So, I think a total solution will probably require that you fiddle around a bit with a helper function. The following just demonstrates that you can add multiple primitives. If you set EdgeShapeFunction like this, `EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Lighter[Blue], Arrow[#1, 0.3], Red, Line[#1]} &)`, then you get this:
[image]

So, what I would probably do is create your own function that figures out the right combination of lines and arrows, maybe shortens the arrow to avoid overlap, etc etc.

Comment: Clever approach lericr ... still seems like the actual arrowhead color is tricky ... prg

Comment: thank u both; very nice ideas!